# Creating a Vector (physics) Class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a vector (like in physics) class in Java.
I want to support vector addition, dot product, scalar multiplication, etc.
So, my question is, is it possible to do this with generics? Generics can only take objects as parameters but I'd like to use primitives (double or float).

Comment: If you are doing serious physics calculations (modelling, processing large amount of data) consider using native math extensions or go to C++. Boxed numerics are not designed to be used in heavy calculation.

Comment: Are you asking about whether using Generics for a vector class can be done in Java specifically? If so, stackoverflow would be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

It won't work with `double` or `float` because as you noticed you can't create a generic for primitive types. But it will work with the boxed types [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html). Due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) this won't make much of a difference in practice.

That means you can create a generic which can be used with anything that extends [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) with `public class PhysicsVector<T extends Number>`.

Unfortunately you can't do arithmetics on `Number`. That means all your methods will have to convert the values to their floating point representation by calling `.doubleValue()` on them.

Comment: Thank you! One more question, if I were to implement my vector using an array,  should I have my array as an array of T[] or Number[]?

Comment: @Daniel I would use `T[]` unless you want to support vectors where the x-coordinate is of a different type than the y-coordinate. But that might make some vector-operations quite complicated.

Comment: Why not make it `double[]`? Are you really going to get benefits from the extra complexity of using genetics and the space & time overhead of boxing?

Answer (score 1):

@Philipp's answer is right on for your direct question but let's step back to revisit assumptions.

First assumption: You're using Java 8 or earlier. (A future version will support [Generics over Primitive Types](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/218).)

Second, why use generics here? Potentially to save space if you have a very large number of vectors in memory, but boxing will take more space per vector than saved by using `float` instead of `double`. A 3D vector object holding 3 `Double` or `Float` values will require 4 heap nodes and consequent indirection and CPU cache misses.

Generics will add complexity as well as space and time overhead. Generified code will do all the math with `double` values so it won't save CPU math time, in fact it'll cost extra math time converting `float` values to `double`.

The space overhead goes down if you store all the values in a `double[]` or `float[]` since it's a single box for all the values, but there's still an extra heap node per instance, and now there are array bounds checks on every number fetch and store.

If you really want to save space with a very large number of vectors in memory, the way to do it in Java 8 is to have an abstract `Vector` class with an API that uses `double` values, and `FloatVector` and `DoubleVector` subclasses that directly hold 3 primitive values.

Again, if you don't have a lot of them in memory, just go for a simple `Vector` class that holds `double` (or `float`) values.